# Saving graphs in both PDF and PNG format but using PDF files in the final document

Tags: r, knitr

I'm using `knitr` for my analysis. I can save graphs in PDF format with `\SweaveOpts{dev=pdf}` and in PNG format with `\SweaveOpts{dev=png}`. I'm interested to save graphs both in PDF and PNG format in one run but to use the PDF in the final documents interactively.

How can I do this?

Comment: Do you have multiple plots per chunk? If you do not, I can show you a simple approach via a chunk hook; if you do, I will need to change the internal code to allow multiple devices per chunk, e.g. by `dev=c('pdf', 'png')`.

Comment: Thanks @Yihui for your comment. Yes I do have multiple plots per chunk.

Comment: The answer below is a generic solution which does not require one plot per chunk, and I'll think about how to add native support in knitr for multiple devices; maybe this can be done in knitr 0.4.

Comment: That would be great. Thanks Yihui for your nice work.

Comment: OK, I have implemented the support for multiple devices now. See modified answer below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here comes the real solution:

[Knitr 0.3.9](https://github.com/yihui/knitr) starts to support multiple devices per chunk (for now, you have to install from GitHub); in your case, you can set the chunk option `dev=c('pdf', 'png')` to get both PDF and PNG files.

---

Here is a solution that uses ImageMagick to convert PDF files to PNG. Of course you have to install ImageMagick first, and make sure its bin directory is in `PATH`:

```
knit_hooks$set(convert = function(before, options, envir) {
  # quit if before a chunk or no figures in this chunk
  if (before || (n <- options$fig.num) == 0L) return()
  # only convert pdf files
  if (options$fig.ext != 'pdf') return()

  # use ImageMagick to convert all pdf to png
  name = fig_path()  # figure filename
  owd = setwd(dirname(name)); on.exit(setwd(owd))
  files = paste(basename(name), if (n == 1L) '' else seq(n), sep = '')
  lapply(files, function(f) {
    system(sprintf('convert %s.pdf %s.png', f, f))
  })
  NULL
})
```

Basically this hook is executed after a chunk and run `convert foo.pdf foo.png` on all PDF figures. You can use it like

```
<<test-png, convert=TRUE>>=
  plot(1); plot(2)
@
```

Or if you put all figures in a separate directory, you can run `convert` directly in that directory (i.e. do not have to call `system()` in R).

This is not an ideal solution but should work. To make use of R's native `png()` device, you need to answer my question in the above comment first.

Comment: Assuming working with `Rnw` file and generating pdf document: Is there an option to specify which files will be used to generate document? I have a rpeort with large amount of graphics and would like to prearep high and low resolution of it (ie. one using png and one pdf).

Comment: @radek You can do this with LaTeX tricks: http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Importing_Graphics

Comment: Thanks for quick answer. I saw that the generated `tex` file doesn't specify extension of the graphics. Would something like `\DeclareGraphicsExtensions{.pdf}` produce report with pdf images only? Then - I still need to compile two separate tex documents - one with `pdf` option, one with `png`?

Comment: @radek `\DeclareGraphicsExtensions` is the key. You can certainly automate it. Nothing can stop a brave programmer. You can post a new question if you want.